# Programmatically select country and dial code - React-phone-input-2

Tags: reactjs

I am using React-Phone-Input-2 in my project. The code is as follows.

```
<PhoneInput
        country={form.$("country").value}
        value={form.$("phone").value.countryCode}
        enableSearch={true}
        countryCodeEditable={false}
        placeholder=""
        onChange={(phone, country) => {
          debugger;
          field.set(phone);
        }}
        inputProps={{
          name: "countryCode",
          disabled: true,
          "data-test": "Address-phone.countryCode",
        }}
      />
```

This works as expected. I can manually select a country and then the country flag and dial code will be displayed.

Now i have a country drop down. When a country is selected from the country drop down, it should **programmatically change the country code drop down as well**.

I found a similar issue here https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2/issues/101. The demo contains a sample but could not find the source code of the example.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this bug also. This might be applicable to your use case.

```js
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/material.css';
import countryList from 'country-calling-code';
/*
.
.
.
*/
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    country: ''
    phoneNumber: { countryCodeID: '', number: '' },
    phoneHolder: '',
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    phoneNumber: Yup.object({
      countryCodeID: Yup.string(),
      number: Yup.string(),
    }),
  })}
  onSubmit={async (
    values,
    { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }
  ) => {
      try {
        /*
        you may clean your data here then add it to the database, etc.
        */
        setStatus({ success: true });
      } catch (err) {
        /*
        you may display error message here
        */
        setStatus({ success: false });
        setErrors({ submit: err.message });
      }
    }
  }}
>
  {({
    errors,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
    isSubmitting,
    touched,
    values,
  }) => (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        error={Boolean(touched.country && errors.country)}
        fullWidth
        helperText={touched.country && errors.country}
        label="Country"
        margin="normal"
        name="country"
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setFieldValue('state', '', true);
          setFieldValue('phoneNumber', {
            countryCodeID: getCountryID(event.target.value),
            number: values.phoneNumber.number,
          }, true);
          setFieldValue('phoneHolder', `${getCountryID(event.target.value)}${values.phoneNumber.number}`);
          handleChange(event);
        }}
        select
        value={values.country}
        SelectProps={{ native: true }}
        variant="outlined"
      >
        <option key="defult-option" value="Select country">
          Select country
        </option>
        {countryList.map((country) => (
          <option key={country.country} value={country.country}>
            {country.country}
          </option>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      <PhoneInput
        country='us'
        countryCodeEditable={false}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        onChange={(phone, country) => {
          setFieldValue('country', country.name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""));
          setFieldValue('phoneNumber', {
            countryCodeID: country.dialCode,
            number: phone.replace(country.dialCode, ''),
          });
        }}
        value={values.phoneHolder}
      />
      <Button
        color="primary"
        disabled={isSubmitting}
        fullWidth
        size="large"
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
      >
        Submit country
      </Button>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `country`

```
<ReactPhoneInput
        country={userLocale} // userLocale = "us"
        onlyCountries={allowedPhoneRegions}
        placeholder="+23456..."
        id="phoneNumber"
/>
```